# Create android apk manually via command line (Makefile)

Tags: android, c++, gradle, makefile, android-ndk

## Problem

I want to create an android app

- via a `vim` & `makefile` only
- no gradle, no ant, no maven, no android.mk and all other stuff

## Why?

It is a high performance C++ code that is wrapped for an android device.

- Ergo, I do not need 99% of gradles services
- 15+ seconds built time via gradle for a small program? That is unacceptable.
- The incorporation of native code in gradle is ridiculous. These gradle guys come up with an *experimental* ndk plugin that keeps changing syntax.
- I only target ARMv8-A. I will have partly AARCH64 assembler code. And I use a pre-processor m4 that generates `*.cpp` before they get compiled. Can't imagine gradle has something for this.

## My Progress

I know that the following steps are **REQUIRED**:

1. Create *keystore* by `keytool` from `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.
2. Compile source files via `javac` from `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.
3. Create *Dalvik Executables*  for the device by `dx` from `$ANDROID_HOME/built-tools`.
4. Create the `.apk` file by `aapt` from `$ANDROID_HOME/built-tools`.
5. Sign apk package by `jarsigner` from `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.
6. Align apk package by `zipalign` from `$ANDROID_HOME/built-tools`.
7. Install software on phone by `adb` from `$ANDROID_HOME/tools`.

The app crashes on startup. Even when I want to create a blank activity.

-

Comment: You should probably provide some more details if you want anyone to be able to help with this: e.g. show the code you're compiling, the exact commands you're using for building (i.e. including all arguments/switches), and the logcat output from the crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, I figured it out. I placed my sample code on https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line

Hope it helps you guys too.

Comment: That link leads to a 404 page. Do you have the code up elsewhere?

Comment: I did this and it works, however when I run the app in the emulator I always get a warning: "This app was built for an older version of Android and may not work properly." I made sure it's using the correct build-tools directory and the android.jar from the correct platform version folder. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by your work, I published a similar package. However, I use a simple `make.sh` script instead of `Makefile` (because I had issues interpreting its syntax). https://github.com/Kolodez2106/HelloWorld-app-compiled-in-bash

Comment: I did this and it works, however when I run the app in the emulator I always get a warning: "This app was built for an older version of Android and may not work properly." I made sure it's using the correct build-tools directory and the android.jar from the correct platform version folder. What else do I need to do?

Comment: What happens if you run the app on a real device?